# Using YouTube  login with Omniauth, Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, youtube, omniauth

I am creating an application that uses [OmniAuth](http://intridea.com/2010/10/4/omniauth-flexible-authentication-for-rack?blog=company) exclusively for logins, that is, users can log in using their various accounts from around the Internet.  My site involves videosharing, so I would love to be able to have users login using their YouTube account.

I've successfully implemented: Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, [foursquare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foursquare_%28social_network%29), [Vimeo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimeo) and [Netflix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix).

However I am having trouble getting it to work with YouTube. Mainly, I don't know how I should be formatting the code in my initalizer. I've got this thus far:

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
  provider :facebook, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
  provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
  provider :foursquare, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
  #provider :linkedin, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
  provider :netflix, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
  #provider :tumblr, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
  #provider :youtube, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
  provider :vimeo, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
end
```

I would assume YouTube is similar in setup, as they are both run by Google, but I have yet to be able to find any information from either the OmniAuth end or the YouTube end.

Any suggestions?

Information on [Tumblr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumblr) or [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) that would be useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[omniauth / oa-oauth / lib / omniauth / strategies / you_tube.rb](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/oa-oauth/lib/omniauth/strategies/you_tube.rb) is about OmniAuth's YouTube strategy. It should work with:

```
provider :youtube, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
```

Comment: this is true.  it was just a matter of figuring out where i had to get the consumer_key and secret from. Here: https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains

Answer (score 1):

You should use underscore in provider name because file is you_tube.rb

provider :you_tube, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'